# Using global variables in netlogo procedure

Tags: function, netlogo

I am trying to create two globals, g1 and g2, which will take on values of 10 and 9 respectively. They will then be passed in a function, titled func1_mod. I am using the following code so far:

```
globals [
  g1  
  g2
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set g1 10
  set g2 9
  reset-ticks
end

to-report func1_mod 
   report (g1 / g2) + .05 * (g1 / g2)  * (1 - (g1 / g2))
end
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Division by zero.
error while observer running /
  called by procedure NEXTVP_MOD
  called by Command Center
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: How are you calling the function? Have you run `setup` first? If I run `setup` then `func1_mod` in my Command Center I get a value (1.104....)

Comment: I am running the above code in the code area and then running 'nextVP_mod .01' in the command center. What did you run in the command center?

Comment: Your problem most likely stems from g2 not being defined and thus defaulting to zero. As long as you run setup before running func1_mod it should be alright.

Comment: Simply writing the code down in the code tab is not enough to run it. You still need to do that by either giving the command in the command center or by having a button that runs that piece of code